# Resolutions for Android app

Tags: android, xamarin

I have app for Android. It supports hd, full hd and qhd resolutions.

But it doesn't support 960*540 and 800*480 resolutions.

I want to ask, do i need to make screens for these resolutions or no?

If no, how i can make that app will not install on phone with these resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Well

> I have app for Android. It supports hd, full hd and qhd resolutions.

here as mentioned hd,full hd all are device density.

> 960*540 and 800*480 resolutions.

here as mentioned number are device pixel ratio.

above mentioned both are different. One device can fall have larger size but less pixel than that device wont fall in hd bucket. 
most of the times we handle these issues in the mdpi bucket.

> I want to ask, do i need to make screens for these resolutions or no?
>
> yes. if you want support these screen and your existing screen are not falling in these screen buckets.
>
> If no, how i can make that app will not install on phone with these resolutions?
>
> make use mdpi bucket

Comment: Okay 

I have these folders in Resources - 

layout-normal-long-port 
layout-normal-notlong-port-xhdpi  
layout-normal-notlong-port 
layout


how I can make that on 960*540 and 800*480 my design will look good?

Or how can I block these resolutions?